# Excel VBA add new row to SumIf

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel Workbook i have a Table and a UserForm. With the UserForm i add new rows to my table. In the last row, from "N" to "BI" of my table i have a SumIf Formula.

So when i add the new row, the SumIf Formula jumps into the next row, but i don´t know how to write the code that the new row will be added to the SumIf Formula.

This is the code for the new row:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "A").EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "A").Value = TextBox1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "B").Value = TextBox2
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "C").Value = TextBox3
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "D").Value = TextBox4  

    AcitveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, Range("N:BI")).FormulaR1C1 = 'Here i don't know what to write
```

Also the part Range("N:BI") causes an error. How do i have to write this that it works?

Hope some one can help me. Thanks

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys i was out of office.

[image]

In the picture you can see my table. In fact the table shows the working progress of a machine. With the Button in A1 and B1 i can add a new assignment. So the new assignment will be added in row 21 and the row N23 to BI23 (where the SumIf Formula is) jumps to N24 to BI24.

The SumIf Formula looks like this:
=SUM(SUMIF($K$3:$K$19;N3;$L$3:$L$19; .... $K$3:$K$19;N20;$L$3:$L$19))

So if i add a new row, i want that the formula adds the next row. And this for all columns from column N to BI

I hope it is clear now and someone can help me.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using full column references in the sumif?

Comment: How about something like: `ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow + 1 & ":BI" & lastrow + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & lastrow & "]C:R[-1]C)"`

Comment: please write a formula, in detail to see actual problem, screenshot also helpful

Comment: You can read up on R1C1 references, and how to make those relative. This link has some nice examples: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm

Comment: You could also consider using a table and adding a listrow to the table. That way, formulas automatically get added to new rows, no VBA needed. Check out this comment in my article about tables and VBA: https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp?AllComments=True#9496

Comment: @diem_L provide exampel with pictures (source data and expected result). It's difficult to understnad what you're trying to achieve,

Comment: See me edit part. hope it is clear now and someone can help.